# apc_delete no longer deleting cached data

Tags: php, apc

I upgraded to PHP 5.3.19 last night and `apc_delete` is no longer working for me.  I have APC 3.1.13 installed.

Anytime I update a news entry, my code is supposed to delete the stored post in APC.

```
if ($_GET["action"] == "save")
{
     // save the info to mysql database
     ...
     ...
     // delete the post from APC cache
     echo "APC cache post# $sid deleted? - ";
     var_dump( apc_delete("news_$sid") );
}
```

The value always used to return `true` - now it's returning `false`. The stored news post in APC is not deleted.

In fact, trying to delete the stored entry manually (via apc.php script) does not work either. The only way I managed to get the post deleted was to click on the "Clear user Cache" button.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: 3.1.13 is beta.  Can you try the latest stable release instead?  There's been a big period of instability in APC after PHP 5.4 was released.  As you aren't on 5.4, you can safely use an older version here...

Comment: The latest 'stable' APC release will not allow me to store the cache in 'IPC shared memory' - forcing me to use disk instead. It's the main reason why I'm using the latest beta. Frustrating how updating PHP from .18 to .19 would cause these issues.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  I realize this isn't exactly an answer, but have you considered switching to memcached for this?  Unlike APC, it doesn't break every time you look at it funny.

Comment: Actually no, I have not looked at that as a possible option. I'll check it out and see how it goes. Thanks!